# Community Promotion Ads - 2018

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's almost February in 2018, which isn't supposed to be the proper time to cycle these, but for this year it'll be once again, so we'll be refreshing the **Community Promotion Ads** for this year now!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for the mathematically inclined
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2275).

Answer (score 25):

[image: Apply for Wolfram Summer School!]

Comment: Dear friends, **education** in [Wolfram Summer School](https://education.wolfram.com/summer/school) is **free**, the cost is only travel and campus-living charged by Bentley University. Wolfram builds real-fun skill-building career-boosting academic program for 3 weeks in Boston and brings almost 100 top students and professors from around the world. Networking is amazing. **You can be a part of it**. Please **vote** this ad up, **apply** for the program and **spread the word** encouraging your friends and colleagues. Feel free to ask me any questions. Thank you & cheers!

Answer (score 16):

[image: Join the Mathematica chat on StackExchange]

Answer (score 14):

[image: What are the most common pitfalls availing new users?]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Mathematica palette to upload content to StackExchange easily]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Publication quality figure labels with LaTeX and Mathematica]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Mathematica syntax highlighter for LaTeX]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Mathematica Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Network analysis and graph theory package for Mathematica]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Mathematica Programming: An Advanced Introduction]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Animated Mathematica functions]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?]

Answer (score 10):

[image: PackageData.net: Mathematica Package Repository]

Answer (score 9):

[image: A Mathematica package for sharing images and code with StackExchange]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Check out the generative-art tag!]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Load the nets!]

Answer (score 8):

[image: An elementary introduction to the Wolfram Language]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Seamlessly call MATLAB from Mathematica]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Use our data]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Wolfram Programming Lab]

Answer (score 4):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Join the Computer Science Educators Stack Exchange]